# Convert from big ppt or pptx files to PDF by LibreOffice last version is so slow

Tags: libreoffice, openoffice.org, presentation

I have very weird performance issue with libreoffice.
I run this command via php shell_exec():
$libreoffice5.3 --headless -convert-to pdf --outdir /xxx/xx

But for big files like 5MB over, it takes so long time as 5mins around.
I could notice some guys advise me to increase allocated memory for libreoffice but I am not sure how to do it without GUI, since I am using it on virtual machine running Ubuntu16.04.
I just have ssh access to it from my macOS.

Pls help me.

Comment: Did you google how to do it without GUI?

Comment: What is the memory allocated to the VM? What virtual CPU is being used? Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/938139/edit) your question with these information.

Comment: Thanks so much friends!, finally I could solve it. with unoconv I could accomplish my goal.

Comment: unoconv runs on libreoffice and it supports a lot of CLI basis options to tune the performance and settings. recommend it strongly.